# HTML not loading CCS file

Tags: html, css

I've tried so many solutions from other answers but nothing has worked so far. My CSS file is not being used by my HTML, writing CSS in the main HTML file works.

```
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-F3w7mX95PdgyTmZZMECAngseQB83DfGTowi0iMjiWaeVhAn4FJkqJByhZMI3AhiU" crossorigin="anonymous" type="text/css">
    {% load static %}
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" type="text/css">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
```

Comment: Seems like a path issue.  try /static/css/styles.css

Comment: doesn't seem like you're using the right path

Comment: No, your CSS, according to your screenshot, is in `../../static/css/styles.css` relative to the HTML file you are viewing.

Comment: You URL to CSS file is wrong. CSS is not in root dir of (not next to `index.html`). Always check Network tab if it's loaded in first place

Comment: Where should I move my ccs file to then? Should it not be in the ```hello``` folder?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you input a bigger path to your css file since your html is inside Templates/hello as I see and your css is in /static/css/styles.css which is the path that I would sugget you use :   "/static/css/styles.css

Comment: So change the ```href``` in line 9 to ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css" type="text/css">```? If that's what you mean I just tried it and it's not made a difference

Comment: Something is not right. I do not know what is in your css file, but it should definitely work.  You use this line of code:  ```<link rel="stylesheet" href="/static/css/styles.css">```   and then in your styles.css file test something. What do you have in your css file?

Comment: You can test if the file is loaded by right clicking the page - Click Inspect - and then at the top bar where you see Elements and Console click on the 2 arrows next to them and select Network.  On network you might be asked to hit Ctrl+R and then you will see all the files that are loaded, where you should see "styles.css"

Comment: Interesting, just did as you said and it's giving me a 404 error for styles.css

Comment: Did you test in the Network tab if your css file is loading?

Comment: Yes, I followed your steps above and after pressing Ctrl + R I can see that my html page gets the status code 200 (makes sense as it loads fine) but the next row down shows that my styles.css file is getting status code 404

Comment: It just shows 404 status code but doesn't explain why

Answer (score 0):

When you add an external CSS file to your HTML document, you need to add the rel="stylesheet" attribute to the  tag to make it work.

```
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

If you omit the rel attribute from the  tag then the style won’t be applied to the page.

If you have the CSS file in the same folder as the HTML document, then you can add the path to the CSS file directly as shown below:

```
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

**If you add a / before the file name, the CSS won’t be applied:**


When your CSS is one folder away, you need to specify the folder name inside the href attribute without the / as well.

**This is wrong:**

```
         <link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/style.css" />
```

**This is correct:**

```
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/style.css" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've just tried what you said and changed my ```href```` to ```href="css/styles.css"``` (i.e no backslash to start) but it didn't change anything. My CSS is still not appearing